# Apache Spark 2.0.1 and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, apache-spark

So, i would like to create an apache spark integration in my spring application by following this guide provided by spring (http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html). Now i have a few questions as it seems that sparks 2.0.1 does not include the spark-assembly jar.

What are my options in proceeding with this as it seems that the integration is dependant on the jar?

If i am able to find the old jar would i be able to use it with apache 2.0.1?

Is there a way to get the jar with apache 2.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right - spark 2.0.1 does not include uber jar with itself like in 1.6.x and below (eg. *spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar*)

Spark 2.0.0+ [spark-release-2-0-0.html](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html) doesn't require a fat assembly uber jar. However when you compare content of `spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0` and libs (content of jar files) in `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\` you can see almost the same content with same classes, packages etc.

> If i am able to find the old jar would i be able to use it with apache 2.0.1?
>   Personally I dont think so. There might be potentionally some problems with backward compatibility and it is weird to have something that was removed in `latest` version.

You are right that [SparkYarnTasklet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-hadoop-spark/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/batch/spark/SparkYarnTasklet.java#L118) need assembly jar because there is some postPropertiesSet validation:

```
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.hasText(sparkAssemblyJar, "sparkAssemblyJar property was not set. " +
                "You must specify the path for the spark-assembly jar file. " +
                "It can either be a local file or stored in HDFS using an 'hdfs://' prefix.");
```

But, this `sparkAssemblyJar` is only used in `sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.jar", sparkAssemblyJar);`

- when you will use `SparkYarnTasklet`, the program will probably fail on validation (You can try to extend `SparkYarnTasklet` and Override `afterPropertiesSet` without validation)

And [documentation about `"spark.yarn.jar:"`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#preparations)

> To make Spark runtime jars accessible from YARN side, you can specify
>   spark.yarn.archive or spark.yarn.jars. For details please refer to
>   Spark Properties. If neither spark.yarn.archive nor spark.yarn.jars is
>   specified, Spark will create a zip file with all jars under
>   $SPARK_HOME/jars and upload it to the distributed cache.

so take a look into properties: `spark.yarn.jars` and `spark.yarn.archive`.
So compare what is `spark.yarn.jar` in 1.6.x- and 2.0.0+

- spark.yarn.jar in 1.6.2 :

> The location of the **Spark jar file**, in case overriding the default location is desired. By default, Spark on YARN will use a Spark jar installed locally, but the Spark jar can also be in a world-readable location on HDFS. This allows YARN to cache it on nodes so that it doesn't need to be distributed each time an application runs. To point to a jar on HDFS, for example, set this configuration to hdfs:///some/path.

- spark.yarn.jar in 2.0.1:

> **List of libraries containing Spark code** to distribute to YARN
>   containers. By default, Spark on YARN will use Spark jars installed
>   locally, but the Spark jars can also be in a world-readable location
>   on HDFS. This allows YARN to cache it on nodes so that it doesn't need
>   to be distributed each time an application runs. To point to jars on
>   HDFS, for example, set this configuration to hdfs:///some/path. Globs
>   are allowed.

but this seems to set all jars one by one.

But in 2.0.0+ there is `spark.yarn.archive` that replaces `spark.yarn.jars` and provide a way how to avoid passing jars one by one - create archive with all jars in root "dir".

I think `spring-hadoop` will reflect changes in 2.0.0+ in a few weeks, but for "quick fix" I will probably try to override `SparkYarnTasklet` and reflect changes for 2.0.1 - as I saw exactly [execute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-hadoop-spark/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/batch/spark/SparkYarnTasklet.java#L65) and [afterPropertiesSet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-hadoop-spark/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/batch/spark/SparkYarnTasklet.java#L118) methods.

Comment: Wow thanks this is some really good advise thanks. I've taken a step back and used spark 1.5.0 for now as time is not on my side but would like to upgrade to 2.0.0+ soon which this information would help tremendously